# get all values in tuple list after certain index and find highs and lows by second element

Tags: python

```
original_list = [(0.0, 222.4), (1.0, 223.45), (2.0, 224.55), (3.0, 225.7), (4.0, 224.8), (5.0, 224.75), (6.0, 224.45), (7.0, 224.35), (8.0, 225.05), (9.0, 225.9), (10.0, 225.4)]
after_indexing = [] 

index = [i for i,v in enumerate(original_list) if v[0] == 3.0 and v[1] == 225.7]
index_of_start = index[0] # returns 3 so print all the values after index 3 
        
for i in range(len(original_list)):
    if index_of_start + 1 < len(original_list) :
        index_of_start += 1
        start_to_end = original_list[index_of_start]
        after_indexing.append(start_to_end) 
                

print(after_indexing)  
after_indexing.sort(key=lambda x:x[1]) # sorting list by second element to find highs and lows 
print('find_high_low_from_this_list',after_indexing)
print('min is ',after_indexing[0],'max is ',after_indexing[-1])
```

final result is  high =  (min is  (7.0, 224.35) max is  (9.0, 225.9)

It is working but can it be optimized so that i don't need to append items in second list, like by slicing the original list from index 3  and finding highs and lows from it

Comment: Are you aware of slices, i.e. ``original_list[index[0]:]``? Are you aware of ``list.index``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use `list` slices, and `min` and `max` accept key functions, so you can sort by the second element:

```
x = [(0.0, 222.4), (1.0, 223.45), (2.0, 224.55), (3.0, 225.7), (4.0, 224.8), (5.0, 224.75), (6.0, 224.45), (7.0, 224.35), (8.0, 225.05), (9.0, 225.9), (10.0, 225.4)]

>>> min(x[3:], key=lambda x: x[1])
(7.0, 224.35)
>>> max(x[3:], key=lambda x: x[1])
(9.0, 225.9)
```

`x[3:]` makes a slice, where first 3 elements are not present

Also not sure why you save the index in the first tuple position, you don't really need it here.